# Using two CDI producers for the same class in separate packages (Intellij)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a simple app that uses CDI (I'm developing in Intellij IDE).
The initialization uses a producer

```
   @Produces
   public @Alg int getExperimentSize() {
       return 1000;
   }
```

I would like to have two configurations for two separate main files (let's say one with 1000 and one with 100). This results in an "Ambiguous dependencies" error. I tried making the producers private and also move the main files to different packages, but they are still visible to one another and the error persists.

Is it possible to run two different main functions with different injections on the same Intellij project?

Edit: Following a comment from @Smutje, I give a more elaborate example:
Assume we have an interface

```
public interface SortingAlgorithm <T extends Comparable<T>>{
    void sort(T[] array);
}
```

Class AlgorithmRunner gets injected with such an attribute

```
public class AlgorithmRunner {
    @Inject @Quad
    SortingAlgorithm quadraticAlgorithm;
}
```

Team A develops a class implementing the interface

```
public class BubbleSort implements SortingAlgorithm{
}
```

and injects it using a producer

```
    @Produces
    private  @Quad
    SortingAlgorithm makeQuadSortingAlg() {
        return container.instance().select(BubbleSort.class).get();
    }
```

Team B, which is not aware of team A, has its own implementation and would like to add a corresponding producer. I would like to illustrate this situation in my intellij project.

Comment: read about 'alternatives'

Comment: Alternatives requires using the beans.xml (BTW, is it possible to have two beans.xml files in a single project?) 
I'm trying to find a way that does not depend on external configuration.

Comment: 1: This is in **no way** intellij related. 2: If you don't want **anyone** to specify what to use and there are two implementations, how can the software decide this? It can't, hence the 'Ambiguous dependency' error. **Someone** has to specify/configure something. And a `beans.xml` with the alternative in there, how is that 'external'? I can think of serveral other ways to select the right implementation, but they all require 'congfiguration' Developers are the only ones who can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to have two separate Java classes being producers?

In situations like these, when I want to support configurable behaviour I usually would have one producer that produces the configuration and that loads its configurations from e.g. a properties file on `@PostConstruct` - so I have a single producer (no ambiguous dependencies) but also no hard-coded values.

Comment: I am a lecturer, and I would like to illustrate how two different teams use different configurations independently. This means that each team has only a single injection value they use, and might even not know of alternative values.

Comment: Yeah, but how is your setup concerning using different configurations during runtime? Are you creating the applications artifacts with changing dependencies depending on the team?

Comment: Yes, Different teams might use different implementations to the same interface (And not necessarily know of different implementations). When they run their application, they will bind the dependencies to their implementation.

In the original question I asked about injecting an int, but the same question applies for non-primitive types as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "different implementations to the same interface" in combination with CDI producers - maybe expand your question with a runnable example that produces errors instead of talking about a theoretical situation, because your errors above are normal but I understand that your "production" environment is different so the situation you described does not match the situation you will encounter later.

Comment: I updated my question and added a second, more elaborate example.